# AFNetworking enqueRequestOperations triggers completion before all AFJSONRequestOperation completions are called

Tags: ios, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com"]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
NSURLRequest *r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:r success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation1 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:r success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];

[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:@[operation, operation1] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"%@", operations);
}];
```

enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations completion is triggered before operation and operation1 blocks.

Did read https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/362 and tried possible fix with dispatch_group but it's still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use AFHTTPRequestOperation instead of AFJSONRequestOperation and parse the JSON manually using NSJSONSerialization and you will find your queue completion block fires after all operations have completed as required.